# Openshift and net-ssh incompatibility? (2.9.3-beta1 vs 2.9.2)

Tags: ruby, windows, postgresql, openshift, net-ssh

by searching to access my Postgres DB on Openshift, i'm currently facing problem using net-ssh.

- At this step - note that the installed Ruby version is 2.2.0 and net-ssh is 2.9.3-beta1

To be able to access the DB from my local DB IDE, i need to execute:
`rhc port-forward myappname`

But the execution returns this error: `Checking available ports ... Could not parse PKey: no start line`

As you can see in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28682443/openshift-port-forwarding) (an other ones [e.g. this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221319/unable-to-login-to-openshift)), the fix is to back to a stable version of net-ssh. the 2.9.2.
What i've succesfully done.

But now, running `rhc port-forward myappname` is giving me the following error: `.../2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require': cannot load such file`

And the fix is to upgrade net-ssh to the 2.9.3-Beta1 version (see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29593646/error-setting-up-rhc-red-hat-client-tools)).

This is really weird! Seems that "the snake is biting its own tail" (don't know if that french expression got english translation).

Note that i've tried to make a clean setup with new ssh key gen (automatically and manually).
My system is runnin' Win 7 64bits.

I made uninstall/install of last version of Ruby.
Reinstall of rhc.
Last version running on rhc-1.36.4. The problem goes on.

Can you help?
Should i install an older version of ssh-net and/or Ruby (i'm not allowed to use ssh-net 2.5.2 due to new version of rhc)?

(sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an older version of Ruby, try 1.9.3 or 2.0, or maybe even 2.1.

Comment: Alright!
Ruby 2.1.6 and net-ssh 2.9.2 solved my problem
Thank you @corey112358

Comment: this seems to be the problem https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_0/NEWS#L148-L149

Answer (score 5):

rhc/Gemfile & rhc/rhc.gemspec required `gem "net-ssh", "<= 2.9.2"`
net-ssh version 2.9.2 use `require dl/import` atleast on pageant.rb

`dl/import` is removed from ruby see https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_0/NEWS#L148-L149
instead fiddle is recommended

net-ssh 3.* seems to fix this(uses fiddle/{import,*{ for ruby >= 2.1)

net-ssh version 3.* seems to have drop in compatibility(still working on mine) for rhc

So a simple hack is to modify rhc/Gemfile & rhc/rhc.gemspec and install the gem
A guy already have done it.

**A Solution**(Untested)

```
gem 'rhc', :git => 'git://github.com/thrasher-redhat/rhc.git'
```

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7421712/2382629

**Alternative Solution**(Tested even on windows 7 32bit :p)

```
git clone https://github.com/openshift/rhc
cd rhc
```

modify rhc/Gemfile & rhc/rhc.gemspec like https://github.com/openshift/rhc/pull/748/files then

```
gem build rhc.gemspec
```

it should output like

```
blah! blah! blah! warnings and msgs......
Successfully built RubyGem
Name: rhc
Version: 1.38.4
File: rhc-1.38.4.gem
```

then run

```
gem install rhc-1.38.4.gem
```