# rhc setup gives error `no such file dl/import` still

Tags: ruby, openshift

I'm installing openshift client tools as described: https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-windows.html#client-tools. On step 'Setting up Your Machine' I got an error.

> rhc setup
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
>   `require' : cannot load such file -- dl/import (LoadError)

The solution the problem [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896733/rhc-setup-gives-error-no-such-file-dl-import) but it's not working for me, even after I installed the gem and run

```
rhc setup
```

I'm still getting the same errors. What am I doing wrong? I downloaded Ruby 2.2.3 (x64) and I'm on windows 7.

Comment: Just a guess but I think it doesn't work on version 2.2. I have seen this question a lot. I installed 2.0 and it worked fine.

Comment: do I have to open the command prompt as administrator?

Comment: Not sure.  But worth a try.  I'm always set to administrator.

Comment: yea, that worked, just install version 2.0 instead of anything later, thanks.

Comment: I had the same issue. Look this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28959533/2788478

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rhc setup gives error \`no such file dl/import\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896733/rhc-setup-gives-error-no-such-file-dl-import)

Comment: I have solved this... this particular QS have many duplicates ... my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/q/31906673/2382629

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install Ruby 2.0.0-p647 (x64) and not the later versions. suggested by  fat fantasma in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the cmd.

> gem install net-ssh -v 2.9.3.beta1

Comment: No. `$ gem install net-ssh -v 2.9.3.beta1
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'net-ssh' (= 2.9.3.beta1), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)  `  Is it just me, or is RHC just too fragile?  This happens each time I need to use OpenShift...